# How does one add certificate_authorities to CertificateRequest message in TLSv1.3

Tags: java, jsse, mutual-authentication, tls1.3

I'm setting up mutual authentication using TLS 1.3 using a spring boot server and curl client for testing. My truststore containts two certificate chains which are loaded correctly - in fact the mutual authentication works in this test setup.

However, based on the [RFC8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.2.4) spec I'm trying to get the `CertificateRequest` message in the SSL Handshake to contain the  `certificate_authorities` extension.

The logging (`-Djavax.net.debug=all`) shows the certificate request message from the sever, without `certificate_authorities`.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|13|https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2|2020-02-17 14:24:15.419 CET|CertificateRequest.java:864|Produced CertificateRequest message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate_request_context": "",
  "extensions": [
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1]
    }
  ]
}
)
```

This extension is optional to send in the `CertificateRequest`, but I would like to include it in this message so that the real client device will be able to send the correct certificate to the server based on this.

Answer (score 0):

While researching this issue I came across [JDK-8206925](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206925) which states that

> The current TLS 1.3 implementation does not support this function [...]

So apparently its just an open issue for java (or at least the openJDK java that I use).

I'm happy to be proven wrong though..